# WaveletListPlot: Broken in 11.2?

Tags: plotting, wavelet-analysis

I'm trying to create a `WaveletListPlot`, following the [reference code](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaveletListPlot.html) exactly:

```
d1 = Table[Sin[x] + Cos[2 x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/511}];
d2 = Table[ArcSin[Sin[20 x]]/5, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/511}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[d1 + d2, SymletWavelet[4], 6];
WaveletListPlot[dwd, DataRange -> {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> "", 
 FillingStyle -> Brown, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

However, I do not get the same image as the documentation, namely, I don't get vertical lines for the wavelet coefficients, I get multiple time-series:

[image]

as opposed to the documentation picture, which is what I want:

[image]

How can I make the wavelet list plot give me vertical bars?

Comment: I get the correct plot in v.9, but reproduce your problem with v.12.

Comment: Even in the simple example in the documentation in v.12, `Joined->False` fails in `WaveletListPlot`.

Comment: Also fails on 12.1. I have reported it on the 12.1 bug tracker Issue # 247.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: Dunno if y'all work for Mathematica, but is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Joined -> {False}`:

```
Row[WaveletListPlot[dwd, DataRange -> {-2 π, 2 π}, 
     #, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16], 
     Filling -> Axis, PlotMarkers -> "", FillingStyle -> Brown, Frame -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
   {Joined -> False, Joined -> {False}}, Spacer[15]]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

on Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial workaround.

```
d1 = Table[Sin[x] + Cos[2 x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/511}];
d2 = Table[ArcSin[Sin[20 x]]/5, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], (4 \[Pi])/511}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[d1 + d2, SymletWavelet[4], 6];

d = Normal[dwd];
plots = ListPlot[#[[2]], Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> Brown, PlotMarkers -> "", 
    DataRange -> {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, Ticks -> None, 
    AxesOrigin -> {-6.5, 0}, AspectRatio -> .1] & /@ 
  d[[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 11}]];

GraphicsColumn[plots, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Or with some labels:

```
axis = ListPlot[d[[2, 2]], PlotMarkers -> "", 
  DataRange -> {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, AxesOrigin -> {-6.5, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> .1, Ticks -> {Automatic, None}, 
  Axes -> {Automatic, None}];
Grid[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "", ""}, Append[plots, axis]}]]
```

[image]